# Исправить ошибки чтения с флешки FAT32

Tags: ubuntu, usb, диск, fat32

При подключении флешки к Ubuntu выдается окно:

```
Не удалось показать всё содержимое объекта «Transcend»: 
Ошибка при получении информации о файле «/media/hostel/Transcend/T┬¿▌▐|.k¡»: Ошибка ввода/вывода
```

`ls -la` выдает это:

```
ls: невозможно получить доступ к '½è'$'\032''v]^1µ.nzg': Ошибка ввода/вывода
ls: невозможно получить доступ к 'T┬¿'$'\035''▌'$'\f''▐|.k'$'\016''¡': Ошибка ввода/вывода
ls: невозможно получить доступ к ' '$'\034''efτ'$'\017''µé.ñ┤%': Ошибка ввода/вывода
ls: невозможно получить доступ к '┴╞í.}btá.ëuü': Ошибка ввода/вывода
ls: невозможно получить доступ к ''$'\b''ƒ$v'$'\034''⌡É▌.╢B│': Ошибка ввода/вывода
```

Файловая система FAT32. В Windows вообще говорит, что "отформатируйте диск".

Что произошло? Полетела таблица FAT? Вирус-шифровальщик? Как понять и исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Это китайская флешка. Заявленный размер значительно превышает реальный (в 4 раза и более).

Как проверить реальный размер флешки:

1. Отформатировать флешку в fat32 или в любую другую файловую систему. Посмотреть размер - будет чуть-чуть меньше заявленного (иногда больше, или примерно столько же)
2. Записать на нее каких-нибудь файлов на весь размер флешки (аудио-книги, коллекция mp3 и т.п.)
3. После того как память на флешке закончится, безопасно (!!) извлечь из usb и выдернуть физически.
4. Воткнуть обратно (можно в другой usb), примонтировать к ОС и скопировать все содержимое флешки снова на жесткий диск, после этого попытаться прочитать какие-либо файлы с жесткого диска.

В случае, если на каком-либо из этапов получим описанную в вопросе ошибку (т.е. кракозябры в названиях файлов/дирректорий и невозможность прочитать инфу с флешки/диска), повторяем все операции, но общий размер файлов делаем в 2 раза меньше - так выясняем реальный размер флешки..

---

P.S. такая флешка может стать *приятным* подарком другу или *сикретной* флешкой. (!!)

P.P.S. у меня было пара таких - повыкидывал сгоряча..

Comment: Для этого, к слову, специальные программы есть: https://github.com/AltraMayor/f3